# Pytorch-Restnet image classification model is unable to predict the labels of images when I save the model and then load it

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have trained an image classification model using PyTorch and ResNet architecture, and it is working fine when I use it for predictions immediately after training. However, I encountered an issue when I saved the trained model as an 'h5' file using PyTorch's torch.save() function, and then tried to load and use it for prediction later. This is strange as I just tried to predict the labels of the same images on which the model was trained. I'm completely new to AI and I do not understand why this is happening.

Here is the  code which I use to load and predict the labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import torch
import torchvision
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm
import torchvision.models as models


model0 = torch.load('./new_file.h5')
model0.eval()

transform = ToTensorV2()

image_path = "./s1.png"
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = transform(image=image)["image"]
image = image.unsqueeze(0)  
#image = 
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model0(image.float())
    probabilities = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    predicted_class = torch.argmax(probabilities, dim=1)

# Get the predicted label
label_names = ['helical', 'skyrmions']  
predicted_label = label_names[predicted_class.item()]

print (predicted_class.item())

# Display the image and predicted label
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title(f"Predicted Label: {predicted_label}")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Here the model is always predicting the label as `0`, even when we supply the training images whose label was 1. However, when the model is predicting immediately after training it is making the right predictions.

Here is the full code which trains the model. I wrote this based on this [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/iamleonie/pytorch-image-classification-tutorial-for-beginner).

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from types import SimpleNamespace
import os
from albumentations.pytorch import ToTensorV2
import albumentations as A
import timm
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  # linear algebra
import pandas as pd  # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)
cfg = SimpleNamespace(**{})
cfg.root_dir = './images/'
cfg.n_classes = 2
cfg.batch_size = 32
cfg.image_size = 256
cfg.backbone = "resnet18"
cfg.pretrained = True
cfg.pretrained_weights = None
cfg.learning_rate = 1e-4
cfg.lr_min = 1e-5
cfg.epochs = 5
cfg.seed = 42
cfg.n_folds = 3  # 5
cfg.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
cfg.num_workers = 4
sub_folders = ["helical/", "skyrmions/"]
labels = [0, 1]
data = []
print(cfg.root_dir)
for s, l in zip(sub_folders, labels):
    # print (s,l)
    for r, d, f in os.walk(cfg.root_dir + s):
        for file in f:
            # print (file)
            if ".png" in file:
                # print ('found image')
                data.append((os.path.join(s, file), l))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['file_name', 'label'])
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=cfg.seed).reset_index(
    drop=True)  # , inplace=True)
df.head()
df.label.value_counts()
df.info()
test_len = 8
test_df = df[-test_len:].reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[:-test_len]
test_df


def set_seed(seed=1234):
    random.seed(seed)
    os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(cfg.seed)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False


class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,
                 cfg,
                 df,
                 transform=None,
                 mode="val"):
        self.root_dir = cfg.root_dir
        self.df = df
        self.file_names = df['file_name'].values
        self.labels = df['label'].values
        if transform:
            self.transform = transform
        else:
            self.transform = A.Compose([
                A.Resize(cfg.image_size, cfg.image_size),
                ToTensorV2(),])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Get file_path and label for index
        label = self.labels[idx]
        file_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.file_names[idx])

        # Read an image with OpenCV
        image = cv2.imread(file_path)

        # Convert the image to RGB color space.
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Apply augmentations
        augmented = self.transform(image=image)
        image = augmented['image']

        # Normalize because ToTensorV2() doesn't normalize the image
        image = image/255

        return image, label


example_dataset = CustomDataset(cfg, df)

example_dataloader = DataLoader(example_dataset,
                                batch_size=cfg.batch_size,
                                shuffle=True,
                                num_workers=0,)


def calculate_metric(y, y_pred):
    metric = accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
    return metric


def train_one_epoch(dataloader, model, optimizer, scheduler, cfg, lrs):
    model.train()
    final_y = []
    final_y_pred = []
    final_loss = []
    for step, batch in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader)):
        X = batch[0].to(cfg.device)
        y = batch[1].to(cfg.device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        with torch.set_grad_enabled(True):
            y_pred = model(X)
            loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
            y = y.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
            y_pred = y_pred.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
            final_y.extend(y)
            final_y_pred.extend(y_pred)
            final_loss.append(loss.item())
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        lrs.append(optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"])
        scheduler.step()
    loss = np.mean(final_loss)
    final_y_pred = np.argmax(final_y_pred, axis=1)
    metric = calculate_metric(final_y, final_y_pred)

    return metric, loss, lrs


def validate_one_epoch(dataloader, model, cfg):
    model.eval()
    final_y = []
    final_y_pred = []
    final_loss = []
    for step, batch in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader)):
        X = batch[0].to(cfg.device)
        y = batch[1].to(cfg.device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            y_pred = model(X)
            loss = criterion(y_pred, y)
            y = y.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
            y_pred = y_pred.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
            final_y.extend(y)
            final_y_pred.extend(y_pred)
            final_loss.append(loss.item())
    loss = np.mean(final_loss)
    final_y_pred = np.argmax(final_y_pred, axis=1)
    metric = calculate_metric(final_y, final_y_pred)
    return metric, loss


def fit(model, optimizer, scheduler, cfg, train_dataloader, valid_dataloader=None):
    lrs = []
    acc_list = []
    loss_list = []
    val_acc_list = []
    val_loss_list = []
    for epoch in range(cfg.epochs):
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{cfg.epochs}")
        set_seed(cfg.seed + epoch)
        acc, loss, lrs = train_one_epoch(
            train_dataloader, model, optimizer, scheduler, cfg, lrs)
        if valid_dataloader:
            val_acc, val_loss = validate_one_epoch(
                valid_dataloader, model, cfg)
        print(f'Loss: {loss:.4f} Acc: {acc:.4f}')
        acc_list.append(acc)
        loss_list.append(loss)
        if valid_dataloader:
            print(f'Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f} Val Acc: {val_acc:.4f}')
            val_acc_list.append(val_acc)
            val_loss_list.append(val_loss)
    return acc_list, loss_list, val_acc_list, val_loss_list, model, lrs


model = timm.create_model(cfg.backbone,
                          pretrained=True,
                          num_classes=cfg.n_classes)

X = torch.randn(cfg.batch_size, 3, cfg.image_size, cfg.image_size)
y = model(X)
y.shape

transform_soft = A.Compose([A.Resize(cfg.image_size, cfg.image_size),
                            A.Rotate(p=0.6, limit=[-45, 45]),
                            A.HorizontalFlip(p=0.6),
                            A.CoarseDropout(
                                max_holes=1, max_height=64, max_width=64, p=0.3),
                            ToTensorV2()])

example_dataset = CustomDataset(cfg, df, transform=transform_soft)

example_dataloader = DataLoader(
    example_dataset, batch_size=cfg.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0,)
df["kfold"] = -1
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=cfg.n_folds)
for fold, (train_, val_) in enumerate(skf.split(X=df, y=df.label)):
    df.loc[val_, "kfold"] = fold

for fold in range(cfg.n_folds):
    train_df = df[df.kfold != fold].reset_index(drop=True)
    valid_df = df[df.kfold == fold].reset_index(drop=True)

    train_dataset = CustomDataset(cfg, train_df, transform=transform_soft)
    valid_dataset = CustomDataset(cfg, valid_df)

    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset,
                                  batch_size=cfg.batch_size,
                                  shuffle=True,
                                  num_workers=0,)
    valid_dataloader = DataLoader(valid_dataset,
                                  batch_size=cfg.batch_size,
                                  shuffle=False,
                                  num_workers=0,)

    model = timm.create_model(cfg.backbone,
                              pretrained=True,
                              num_classes=cfg.n_classes)

    model = model.to(cfg.device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                                 lr=cfg.learning_rate,
                                 weight_decay=0,)

    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer,
                                                           T_max=np.ceil(
                                                               len(train_dataloader.dataset) / cfg.batch_size) * cfg.epochs,
                                                           eta_min=cfg.lr_min)

    acc, loss, val_acc, val_loss, model, lrs = fit(
        model, optimizer, scheduler, cfg, train_dataloader, valid_dataloader)


train_df = df.copy()

train_dataset = CustomDataset(cfg, train_df, transform=transform_soft)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset,
                              batch_size=cfg.batch_size,
                              shuffle=True,
                              num_workers=0,
                              )

model = timm.create_model(cfg.backbone,
                          pretrained=True,
                          num_classes=cfg.n_classes)

model = model.to(cfg.device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                             lr=cfg.learning_rate,
                             weight_decay=0,
                             )

scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer,
                                                       T_max=np.ceil(
                                                           len(train_dataloader.dataset) / cfg.batch_size) * cfg.epochs,
                                                       eta_min=cfg.lr_min)

acc, loss, val_acc, val_loss, model, lrs = fit(
    model, optimizer, scheduler, cfg, train_dataloader)

test_dataset = CustomDataset(cfg, test_df)

test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset,
                             batch_size=cfg.batch_size,
                             shuffle=False,
                             num_workers=0,
                             )


# def predict(dataloader, model, cfg):
dataloader = test_dataloader
# Validation mode
model.eval()

final_y = []
final_y_pred = []

# Iterate over data
for step, batch in tqdm(enumerate(dataloader), total=len(dataloader)):
    X = batch[0].to(cfg.device)
    y = batch[1].to(cfg.device)
    print ('X =',X)
    print ()
    with torch.no_grad():
        y_pred = model(X)
        y = y.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
        y_pred = y_pred.detach().cpu().numpy().tolist()
        final_y.extend(y)
        final_y_pred.extend(y_pred)
final_y_pred_argmax = np.argmax(final_y_pred, axis=1)
metric = calculate_metric(final_y, final_y_pred_argmax)
print(metric)
calculate_metric(final_y, final_y_pred_argmax)
test_df['prediction'] = final_y_pred_argmax
test_df

torch.save(model.state_dict(), "trained_model.pth")
torch.save(model, 'new_file.h5')
for (idx, batch) in enumerate(test_dataloader):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(10, 6))
    idx = 0
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(4):
            label = batch[1][idx]
            image = batch[0][idx]
            pred = final_y_pred_argmax[idx]
            # Reshape image
            image = image.permute(1, 2, 0)
            ax[i, j].imshow(image)
            # \n{df.file_name[idx]}")#, fontsize=14)
            ax[i, j].set_title(
                f"Ground Truth: {label} ({'skyrmions' if label == 1 else 'helical'}) \n Prediction: {pred} ({'skyrmions' if pred == 1 else 'helical'}) ")
            ax[i, j].axis('off')
            idx = idx+1
            color = 'green' if label == pred else 'red'
            ax[i, j].add_patch(Rectangle((0, 0), cfg.image_size, cfg.image_size,
                                         alpha=1, edgecolor=color, linewidth=5, fill=None))
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig(f'./inference_prediction.jpg',
                transparent=False,  facecolor='white')
    plt.show()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the loading part?